# Is there a good way to add a trackbar to cv2 Video

Tags: python, opencv, filter

I wanted to add a filter(where everything is grayscaled except for the color chosen) that I can manipulate with a trackbar.
The trackbar shows up but it shows no effect when the video is played.
How should I solve this?
please help, wise people.

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

video = cv2.VideoCapture(FILE_PATH +'/city_ex.mp4')
if not video.isOpened():
    print("Video Open Failed")
    sys.exit()
def trackbar(pos):
    global frame

    h, w = frame.shape[:2]
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (w//2, h//2))
    frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hue_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue_min', 'video')
    hue_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue_max', 'video')

    mask = cv2.inRange(frame_hsv, (hue_min, 0, 0), (hue_max, 255, 255))
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    colored_portion = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    video_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    gray_portion = cv2.bitwise_or(video_gray, video_gray, mask=mask_inv)
    # gray_portion = np.stack((gray_portion,)*3, axis=-1)

    combined = colored_portion + gray_portion

    cv2.imshow('video', combined)

cv2.namedWindow('video')
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue_min', 'video', 0, 179, trackbar)
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue_max', 'video', 0, 179, trackbar)


while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()

    if not ret:
        break
    
    
    frame = show_change(frame)

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    
  

    

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you shouldn't use two times `imshow('video',...)` because it displays in the same window and original `frame` may very fast replace image which you want to display - `combined` - and you may see only original `frame`. You sould use only `cv2.imshow('video', combined)` or you should assign new image to `frame = colored_portion + gray_portion` and use only `cv2.imshow('video', frame)`. Or you should display then in two different widows - with different names.

Comment: in `trackbar()` you should only get values and assing to global variables but modifications you should do in `while True`. At this moment `trackbar` is executed only when you move trackbar and function is executed only once and it create only one image which later is replace in window with original `frame`.

Comment: Oh... Understood. For some reason,  I had cv2.namedWindow('video') and just thought I needed to add imshow() also. Thank you for your help, Mr.Furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems

1. you run two `imshow('video', ...)` so it tries to display two diferent images in the same window and original `frame` may fast replace `combined` so you can see only `frame`. You should use only one `imshow` and display `combined`.
2. `tracebar()` is executed only when you move tracebar and it creates one image only at this. You should use `tracebar()` on to get values and assign to global variables `hue_min`, `hue_max` - and rest you should run in `while True` so it will create `combined` for all frames from file/webcam.

---

My version

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

# --- functions ---

def trackbar(pos):
    global hue_min
    global hue_max
    
    hue_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue_min', 'video')
    hue_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Hue_max', 'video')

# --- main ---

hue_min = 0
hue_max = 179

#FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
#video = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, 'city_ex.mp4'))

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # webcam

if not video.isOpened():
    print("Video Open Failed")
    sys.exit()

cv2.namedWindow('video')
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue_min', 'video', 0, 179, trackbar)
cv2.createTrackbar('Hue_max', 'video', 0, 179, trackbar)

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()

    if not ret:
        break
    
    h, w = frame.shape[:2]
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (w//2, h//2))
    frame_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    mask = cv2.inRange(frame_hsv, (hue_min, 0, 0), (hue_max, 255, 255))
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

    colored_portion = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    video_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    gray_portion = cv2.bitwise_or(video_gray, video_gray, mask=mask_inv)
    # gray_portion = np.stack((gray_portion,)*3, axis=-1)

    combined = colored_portion + gray_portion

    cv2.imshow('video', combined)
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: oh... having global hue_min and hue_max just solved it beautifully. Thank you for your help again.